# Office Web Apps 2010 for SahrePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, office-2010

Does anyone know where to download the setup files for Microsoft Office Web Apps 2010?  We have found service packs for it, but no initial installs.   I've found tons of documentation about how to install it, but none on where to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office Web Apps has no public download. How to get it is described on [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431685%28v=office.14%29). More detailed description is in this [blog post](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=303).